# Getting a span element fill the space in a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have something like this:

```
|--------------fixed width---------------|
 Title1 .......................... value1
 Title2 ................... another value
 Another title ........ yet another value
```

Here is my html example code:

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="left">Title</span>
  <span class="center">&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="right">value</span>
</div>
```

And here my css:

```
.center {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted blue;
    display: inline-block;
    outerWidth: 100%;
}

.right {
    display: block;
    border: 1px dotted red;
    float: right;
}

.left {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px dotted red;
    margin-right: 0px;
    float: left;
}

.container {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px dotted red;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

It's possible to make span "center" expand to fill the space between the other two span elements?

Code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XqHPh/

Thank you!

Comment: You want to create and expand a span for this?

Comment: I think he might want a line of dots...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you reorder your **HTML**, you can get a simple solution:

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="left">Title</span>
  <span class="right">value</span>
  <span class="center">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Place the two floated elements ahead of the `.center` element.  The `.center` element will be in regular content flow and wrap around the left and right content.

The **CSS**:

```
.center {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted blue;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.container {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px dotted red;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

When you float an element, the display type computes to block, so no need to declare it.

Also, for `.center`, if you add `overflow: auto`, you constrain the block so it does not extend beyond the edges of the floated elements.  As a result, your bottom border does not underline the title and value text.

Finally, you can add `position: relative` and move the `.center` up a few pixels to align the border closer to the baseline of the text.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/DPFYD/

Answer (score 7):

for this you need to change the html structure like this

html

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="left">Title</span>
  <span class="right">value</span>
  <span class="center">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

and here is the css for `.center span`

```
.center {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted blue;
    display:block;
}
```

[jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/r2U5L/)

Comment: This is good.  Since the `.center` element is just for visual effect, it does not matter semantically where it appears, so the repositioning is a good call.

Comment: What about `display: inline-block`?

Comment: @David An inline block will shrink-to-fit its content, so it will take more work to make it fill the space between the left and right elements.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile Flexbox has full browser support, which allows for a more elegant solution without the center element.

```css
.left, .right {
    border: 1px dotted red;      
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px dotted red;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="left">Title</span>   
  <span class="right">value</span>
</div>
```