# force element to use 100% of available space between fixed width elements?

Tags: css, html, width

I've got a div being used as a container for 3 other divs. These are all lined up horizontally, using `float:left`. I need the `left` and `right` divs to **keep their same fixed width of 40px**. I want the middle div to expand dynamically - using only CSS if possible.

Here is a JSFiddle I'm experimenting with: http://jsfiddle.net/xJB9n/

If you update the width of my `.middle` CSS class to 620px, this is the result I'm looking for, where the `middle` div is expanded as much as it can, while keeping itself horizontally aligned with the other two divs.

No matter the width of `container` I want the middle div to always expand to 100% of the area that's left, and setting:

```
width: 100%;
```

does not do the trick. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you change the (order) of the markup? And what browsers do you need to support?

Comment: The order could change, I suppose. Do you mean placing the `left` and `right` divs together? They should still *display* in the order I've got them though. And all (major) browsers if possible.

Comment: I mean for example [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Rsb7V/), where the floating elements come first, and the final "middle" div takes up the rest of the space with auto width (and margins so it doesn't overlap the floating sidebars).

Comment: Your solution is exactly what I needed! Thanks - feel free to post as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change the markup, this may work:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>  
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.middle {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 40px;
}  

.left {
    width: 40px;
    float: left;
}

.right {
    width: 40px;
    float: right;
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rsb7V/).

---

Alternatively you can use absolute positioning, though this can be a pain in IE7 and below. This does allow you to keep DOM order though.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>  
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

With this (relevant) CSS:

```
.container { position: relative; }

.left  { position: absolute; left: 0;  top: 0; }
.right { position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; }

.middle { margin: 0 40px; }
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/THRpF/) for a demo.

Comment: This problem is similar to the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064731/getting-a-span-element-fill-the-space-in-a-div/17065194#17065194

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you can use flexbox, but the following works on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

```
.container
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 700px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
}

.left, .right
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: red;
    -moz-box-flex: none;
    -webkit-box-flex: none;
    box-flex: none;
}

.middle
{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
}
```

You can see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sx2Sg/

Comment: IE10 I believe supports flex box, so if you are just looking at modern browsers, you could probably add the -ms prefix to your css.

Answer (score 0):

From your structure.
2 options:

1. `display:table`
2. `display:flex`

`display:table` works fine for all browsers, including IE8.
`Display:flex` is still growing and is not yet mature and many browser has difficulties with it .
I propose then only `display:table;`
http://jsfiddle.net/xJB9n/1/

Don't mistake, it's only CSS, you have no `<table>` in your markup.

Answer (score 0):

In addtion to the css of @Jeroen you need to add one more thing:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.middle {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 40px;
}  

.left {
    width: 40px;
    float: left;
}

.right {
    width: 40px;
    float: right;
}
```

The thing I added is to actually set the `height` to 100%. Without the parent elements' height set 100% you can't apply height 100% to child elements.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/THRpF/1/) for demo.